# How to remove hidden characters in R from string imported from Excel?

Tags: r, excel, string, character, hidden

Using the openxlsx package in R, I am importing data from an Excel file that originated in Brazil. In the character strings, there seem to be hidden characters. As you can see from my code, I remove the white space but strings 2 and 3 are still shown as unique strings.  Strings 6 and 7 are also appearing as unique strings when they should be identical.

```
moths %<>%
  mutate(Details = str_trim(Details))
sort(unique(moths$Details))
```

> [1] "Check Outside"       "Check Plot"
> [3] "Check Plot ​​"                           "Check Plot ​​ (between treatments)"
> [5] "PRX-01GA1-21022.00"                    "PRX-01GA2-22001​"
> [7] "PRX-01GA2-22001"                       "PRX-01GA2-22002​"
> [9] "PRX-01GA2-22002"                       "PRX-01GA2-22003"
> [11] "PRX-01GA2-22004"                       "SF2.5VP"
> [13] "YM001-22"                              "YM001-PRX-01GA2-22001​ PRX-01GA2-22001​"

Unfortunately, since I can't attach the Excel file that the data are coming from, I can't make a completely reproducible example here, but hopefully someone can still provide some insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some non-ascii characters in your data. If you're happy to remove them, you can use [textclean](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/textclean/versions/0.9.3/topics/replace_non_ascii), like so (this example uses the first 4 values of your data):

```
vec <- c("Check Outside", "Check Plot", "Check Plot ​​", 
         "Check Plot ​​ (between treatments)")
unique(vec) 
# [1] "Check Outside"        "Check Plot"  
# [3] "Check Plot ​​"          "Check Plot ​​ (between treatments)"


library(textclean)
vec2 <- replace_non_ascii(vec)
unique(vec2)
# [1] "Check Outside"    "Check Plot"  "Check Plot (between treatments)"
```

So tl;dr this should do what you’re after

```r
library(textclean)

moths <- moths %>%
  mutate(Details = replace_non_ascii(str_trim(Details)))
```

Answer (score 0):

you haven't saved your cleaned data

```
moths %<>%
  mutate(Details = str_trim(Details)) -> moths

sort(unique(moths$Details))
```

Comment: The ```%<>%``` symbols is from the magrittr package and it updates the data frame. It is equivalent to:
```moths <- moths %>%
       mutate(Details = str_trim(Details))```